# Gmail API return an 'Daily Limit Exceeded.' error

Tags: api, gmail

Below is my quota usage and limits in the API Console:

**APIs & Services Gmail API**

**Quotas**

```
Quota Name                          Limit
Queries per day                     500 
Queries per 100 seconds per user    50 
Queries per 100 seconds             50
```

**Metrics**

```
Methods
Method                      Requests  Errors
gmail.users.messages.send   75        46.67%
```

But I got an 'Daily Limit Exceeded' error. What do I do?